# an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion

Tags: scala, null

When doing this:

```
  def myfunction(line: String): (Int, Option[DateTime], Option[Int]) = {
    // do some stuff
    (5, Option(null), Option(null))
  }
```

I get the following:

> an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion

I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: `Int` isn't inhabited by `null`.

Comment: To improve Lee's hint: `Int` will be mapped to the primtive `Int` from JVM in cases where applicable. By thus it isn't possible to use `null` in any case for an Int.

Comment: writing `null` in Scala is somewhat of an anathema...

Comment: tell that to the scalamock people...

Comment: @BoristheSpider  True exept when dealing with database rows: `null` has an important meaning there that can not use `Option` as a substitute. In particular working with `spark udf`s requires handling this properly. It is tricky.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`Option(null)` has a lower bound of `Option[Null]`, where `Null` is the bottom-type of all reference types. `Int` is a value type, and not a reference type. i.e. you can't assign `null` to an `Int`. So you can't assign `Option[Null]` to `Option[Int]`.

Use `Option.empty[Int]` or `None` instead.

Answer (score 1):

One option is using Java native classes. ex: *java.lang.Int*

```
  def myfunction(line: String): (Int, Option[DateTime], Option[java.lang.Int]) = {
        // do some stuff
        (5, Option(null), Option(null))
  }
```

This also works if one of the parameters to the method also defines a primitive type. You can call it using *null*, scala.Int or java.lang.Int and the compiler will figure it all out. ex:

```
 def myfunction(lineCount: java.lang.Integer): (Int, Option[java.lang.Integer], Option[java.lang.Integer]) = {
  // do some stuff
  (5, Option(lineCount), Option(null))
}
```

Note: of course you should avoid using null's in scala, but there are a few scenarios when working with java where this could come up.