# Scala Option type in function parameter - Best Practices

Tags: scala, user-defined-functions, optional-parameters

I'm struggling to understand the nuances of Scala Option, Some classes and hope you could help me out.

As I understand from the documentation, Option[A] types are used when we expect the value to be of Type A or null. Though null type doesn't exist in Scala, the null scenarios can happen when we talk to a non-scale API.

Example - Say I have a function which converts a String to an Integer value

```
 def strToInt(s: String): Option[Int] = {

    val x: Option[Int] = try {
      Some(s.toInt)
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => None
    }

    x

  }

  def stringToInteger(s: String): Int = {

    Option(s) match {
        case None => 0
        case Some(s) => strToInt(s).getOrElse(0)
    }

}
```

Here I have a Wrapper function 'StringToInteger' which checks if the input parameter to the function is a String or null. If null it returns a default integer value of 0 else tries to convert the string to an integer using 'strToInt' function.

However, I seem to run into the following error when the input argument to **stringToInteger** is null.

```
stringToInteger(null)
```

**error: an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion**

Is this an incorrect use of the Option idiom?

Here's another example where I run into the same error. In this case, I'm just checking to see if the input integer parameter is null.

```
def isIntNull(i: Int): Boolean = {

     Option(i) match {
      case None => true
      case Some(i) => false
    }

  }
```

Result -

```
isIntNull(123)
false

isIntNull(null)
Name: Unknown Error
Message: <console>:31: error: an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion
       isIntNull(null)
```

Comment: What version of Scala are you using?

Comment: Also your second function can be re-written without manually having to wrap the argument into an Option... `def stringToInteger(s: String): Int = strToInt(s).getOrElse(0)`

Comment: Hello, I'm using Scala 2.11.

Comment: I'm not having your error when I run your code. Are you sure `StringToInteger` (with upper S) is the same one you pasted here?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203488/an-expression-of-type-null-is-ineligible-for-implicit-conversion

Comment: fixed typo 'StringToInteger' in question. It should have been 'stringToInteger'

Comment: `Int` can't be null as it's mapped to the primitive `int`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because an `Int` in scala is not nullable, it represents a primitive. `null` is only applicable to reference types (sub-types of `AnyRef`), not primitives (sub-types of `AnyVal`).

Also, more idiomatic:

```
import scala.util.Try
Try(s.toInt).toOption
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you say the first example stringToInteger() is valid? I'm not sure why it's throwing the error as the input parameter is a String which belongs to AnyRef.

Comment: @Yash The first example is **not** throwing an error for me, and it seems valid to me. Are you sure you're testing the same code?

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with passing NULL to Option(like Option(null)) in scala 2.11, it throws error - **an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion**

***But it is resolved in 2.12 (I tested it in 2.12.1)***

Answer (score 0):

When to use an Option is a simple matter. If a method tries to access a value that legitimately does not have to exist, that method should return an Option. So a method that gets a user from a database given a user id could return an Option but a function that access a necessary config file should not return an Option.