# Why I can store null in Int when doing conversion from Java but not otherwise?

Tags: scala

In the following code, I am creating a Java collection. Later when I convert it to Scala, I can store `null` in `Int`. But I cannot store `null` if I straightaway create a scala map. Why?

```
scala> import collection.JavaConverters._
import collection.JavaConverters._

scala> val mapJava:java.util.HashMap[String,java.lang.Integer] =  new java.util.HashMap[String,java.lang.Integer]
mapJava: java.util.HashMap[String,Integer] = {}

scala> mapJava.put("key",null)
res2: Integer = null

scala> println(mapJava)
{key=null}

scala> val mapScala = mapJava.asScala
mapScala: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Integer] = Map(key -> null)

scala> val mapScalaI = mapScala.asInstanceOf[scala.collection.Map[String,Int]]
mapScalaI: scala.collection.Map[String,Int] = Map(key -> null) //storing null in Int

//but I cannot store null in Int in following code. why?
scala> val mapScalaI2 = Map[String,Int]("key"->null)
<console>:14: error: an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion
       val mapScalaI2 = Map[String,Int]("key"->null)
                                               ^
```

Answer (score 1):

```scala
...

scala> val mapScala = mapJava.asScala
mapScala: scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Integer] = Map(key -> null)

scala> val mapScalaI = mapScala.asInstanceOf[scala.collection.Map[String,Int]]
mapScalaI: scala.collection.Map[String,Int] = Map(key -> null) //storing null in Int

...
```

Theoretically, `mapScala.asInstanceOf[scala.collection.Map[String,Int]]` should fail because the `Integer` type argument is different from the `Int` type argument. However, it does not actually do so because `asInstanceOf` does not (or cannot) check the type arguments of `Map[String, Int]` due to Java type erasure. From [`scala.Any.asInstanceOf`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.4/scala/Any.html#asInstanceOf[T0]:T0):

> Note that the success of a cast at runtime is modulo Scala's erasure semantics. Therefore the expression `1.asInstanceOf[String]` will throw a `ClassCastException` at runtime, while the expression `List(1).asInstanceOf[List[String]]` will not. In the latter example, because the type argument is erased as part of compilation it is not possible to check whether the contents of the list are of the requested type.

Answer (score 0):

In Java `null` can be value of any reference type, e.g. `java.lang.Integer`.

In Scala `null` is of type `Null`, which is a subtype of any reference type. `scala.Int` is a primitive type, not reference one.

[an expression of type Null is ineligible for implicit conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35203488/an-expression-of-type-null-is-ineligible-for-implicit-conversion)

Comment: That doesn't explain why `mapScala` has value `null` for `key` - `scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,Integer] = Map(key -> null)`